# How to update the state in different mobile screens using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React project, In that I have a button under that I have another div, I written a function if My screen width is 320px then margin-bottom: 150px has to apply under button. it is working fine, but when I am in 320px screen if I click the button then under button margin-bottom: 150px is applied. Here the problem comes now when I go to 375 px here also margin-bottom: 150 px applied automatically. so someone help to how to update state in 375px. Because in 375px screen I have to apply margin-bottom: 300 px.

If you have any questions please let me know thank you.

This is My code

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
    const [style, setStyle] = useState(null)


    function useMediaQuery() {
        const [screenSize, setScreenSize] = useState([0]);
        
        useLayoutEffect(() => {
          function updateScreenSize() {
            setScreenSize([window.innerWidth]);
          }
          window.addEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
          updateScreenSize();
          return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateScreenSize);
        }, []);
        
        return screenSize;
      }


    const [mediaQuery] = useMediaQuery();

    console.log(mediaQuery, '***')

      const applyStyle = () => {
          if(mediaQuery === 320) {
              setStyle({
                  marginBottom: '150px'
              })
          }
      }


    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='first'>
                        <button onClick={applyStyle} style={style}  className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
                        <span className='closeWindow'><i className="far fa-window-close"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='second'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

in App.css write a `@media` query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  button {
    margin-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply media queries in React either programmatically, or using css.

Option 1, using css:

```
.myButton{
  /* media queries */
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    margin-bottom: 150px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 375px) {
    margin-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
```

and then:

```
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <div className='first'>
                        <button onClick={applyStyle}  className='myButton btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
                        <span className='closeWindow'><i className="far fa-window-close"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='second'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Option 2, programmatically:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
    const [mediaMatch, setMediaMatch] = useState();
    const handler = e => setMediaMatch(e.matches);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').addListener(handler);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener(handler);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <div className="first">
                        <button
                            onClick={applyStyle}
                            style={{
                                marginBottom: mediaMatch ? '300px' : '150px'
                            }}
                            className="btn btn-primary"
                        >
                            Click here
                        </button>
                        <span className="closeWindow">
                            <i className="far fa-window-close" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="second" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```